# Podcast Indexed by Google, but not in Assistant Directory. What to do?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

When searching for my podcast in Assistant Directory, the podcast is not found and the podcast is not actionable via the assistant.
(https://assistant.google.com/explore)

Has anyone faced similar difficulties? Would be extremely thankful for some guidance!

I am following Google's documentation on creating a Podcast Action for Google Home.
(https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/podcasts)

My podcast seems to have passed the Google indexing process, as I see direct link is generated:

https://www.google.com/podcasts?feed=aHR0cHM6Ly9ncGlkYWcubGlic3luLmNvbS9yc3M%3D

Podcast is called Nyhetspodden.

Podcast should be listed in Google Assistant Directory and be actionable using voice commands via Assistant/Google Home.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting! The Nyhetspodden podcast's Google Assistant action was successfully auto-generated, but sometimes the invocation instructions can be unclear.

To listen to this podcast on Google Assistant, you can say "Hey Google, play Nyhetspodden podcast".

If your device has a screen, you can type this, like so:

[image: Podcast]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Unfortunately I am still unsuccessful when my device is set to our native Swedish language. Instead other podcasts are being played.

Tried switching to English and yes, I could replicate your screenshot by typing the phrase "Play Nyhetspodden Podcast".

Could it be that the word Nyhetspodden (translated to The News Podcast) is already so closely related to existing actions associated to other podcasts in the news vertical?